# Yii2: Adding two fields and populating third field on the fly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I am trying to populate a total field with id- `#appointment-total_amount` using javascript/jquery. Referring this Jsfiddle [add two fields together](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dj3j/56/) - Which is working fine.

I am using this code in my _form.php

```
<?php
$script = <<<EOD
$(function() {
     $('#appointment-doctor_fee').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    $('#appointment-discount').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    var updateTotal = function () {
      var input1 = parseInt($('#appointment-doctor_fee').val());
      var input2 = parseInt($('#appointment-discount').val());
      $('#appointment-total_amount').text(input1 + input2);
    };

 });
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);        
?>
```

But nothing is happening on the page.

I am not able to see what I am missing here.
Thanks.

**Related HTML**

```
<div class="form-group field-appointment-doctor_fee">
<label class="control-label" for="appointment-doctor_fee">Doctor Fee</label>
<input type="text" id="appointment-doctor_fee" class="form-control" name="Appointment[doctor_fee]" maxlength="10">
</div>


<div class="form-group field-appointment-discount">
<label class="control-label" for="appointment-discount">Discount</label>
<input type="text" id="appointment-discount" class="form-control" name="Appointment[discount]" maxlength="10">

<div class="form-group field-appointment-total_amount">
<label class="control-label" for="appointment-total_amount">Total Amount</label>
<input type="text" id="appointment-total_amount" class="form-control" name="Appointment[total_amount]" maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
$('#appointment-total_amount').text(input1 + input2);
```

Should be:

```
$('#appointment-total_amount').val(input1 + input2);
```

Besides that add at least simple check for illegal numbers, because you will get `NaN` if one of the fields is empty or input value is not valid number. Some range limit will be good too.

```
var updateTotal = function () {
    var doctorFee = parseInt($('#appointment-doctor_fee').val());
    var discount = parseInt($('#appointment-discount').val());
    var totalAmount = doctorFee + discount;

    if (isNaN(totalAmount) || totalAmount < 0 || totalAmount > 100000) {
        totalAmount = '';
    }

    $('#appointment-total_amount').val(totalAmount);
};
```

One more error is in script registration. Change to this:

```
use yii\web\View;

$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
```

Otherwise it will be inserted before jQuery (and your script depends on it) and will not be working.

Registering scripts that way is not good practice, it's even mentioned in official documentation. Separate file and using [assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) is definitely better than struggling with dependencies and inserting js as string (the errors are hard to detect, no autocomplete, etc.).

Comment: Hi arogachev - you suggesting it to be like this - `$('#appointment-total_amount').val(input1 + input2);` and in your code snippet you are using `$('#appointment-total_amount').text(totalAmount);` is it OK. That is text for val

Comment: It's still not working @arogachev. can we add some type of alert to check if anything is working.

Comment: Checked it one more time, works fine. Make sure you have the last version of code, I edited it recently.

Comment: Hi arogachev - I have checked with ur latest code, but nothing seems to happening.

Comment: Post it on JsFiddle or Plunker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69337/discussion-between-arogachev-and-pawan).